# Performing operations and simplification

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The equation is $$2a-7b- \dfrac{4(a^2-16b^2)}{2a-3b}$$

I need to simplify the expression.

Comment: Dear ikaidubidu: the way you've chosen to post this question is below par, and might make you unpopular with the natives if you continue to do so. For one thing, you should include what you have done so far, and then ask a specific question about where you are stuck. If you don't have any progress, it's OK for your specific question to be "where should I begin?" Just posting a problem an saying "I gotta do this" is going to deter a portion of answerers. It's not too late to edit this question, and I wish you luck on future questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the main objective here is simply finding a common denominator, expand, and simplify:

$$\begin{align} 2a-7b- \dfrac{4(a^2-16b^2)}{2a-3b} & = \dfrac{(2a - 7b)(2a - 3b) - 4a^2 + 64 b^2 }{2a - 3b} \tag{1}\\ \\ & = \dfrac{4a^2 -20ab+ 21 b^2 - 4a^2 + 64b^2}{2a - 3b}\tag{2} \\ \\ &= \dfrac{85b^2 - 20ab}{2a-3b} \tag{3}\\ \\ & = \dfrac{5b(17b - 4a)}{2a - 3b}\tag{4}\end{align}$$

$(1)\quad $ Finding the common denominator and subtracting.

$(2)\quad$ Expanding the product in the numerator: $(2a - 7b)(2a-3b)$

$(3)\quad$ Adding/subtracting like terms in numerator.

$(4)\quad$ Factoring out common factor in numerator.

Comment: how did it become -20ab?

Comment: Expand $(2a - 7b)(2a - 3b) = 4a^2 - 14ab - 6ab + 21 b^2 = 4a^2 - 20ab + 21b^2$.

Comment: Hmmm. Looks fine, Amy :-)

Comment: @amWhy $\Huge{+^+}$

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another Tu! =1